# Move files from one folder to another in multiples of 5

Tags: ssis

I want to design an SSIS package to move files from one folder to the other in multiples of 5. For instance, if I have 12 files in my source folder, I need to move files 1 to 5 into Batch1 folder, files 6 to 10 into Batch2 and files 11 and 12 to Batch3. Is there a way to dynamically do this for any number of files in the source folder?

Comment: Tab is right you should use a script task for something like that and use system.io.  one other benefit is you can also split the batches up and generate multiple threads to process more than 1 batch at a time....  AS far as how/ where to start here is a link I would use foreach instead of the counter they use but it works....https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9ad69f90-a24f-44ee-936f-ad876863c82b/move-all-the-files-using-script-task-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 0):

Sure, write a script task that uses the file system object.